# linear, homogeneous recursion, biological interpretation

Tags: recursion, mathematical-modeling

Given the recursion $u_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}(3 u_k - u_{k-1})$
find the expression of $u_k$ in dependence on the values $u_0$ and $u_1$. What is the limit as $ k\rightarrow \infty$ of $\{u_k\}_{k}$?
Give a possible biological interpretation of this recursion.

Hello,

I found  the recursion $u_k= 2u_1-u_0 + 2(u_0-u_1)* (\frac{1}{2})^k$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} u_k=2u_1-u_0$.

But what is missing is the biological interpration. We discuss last lecture time discrete models in population dynamics.$u_k$ means than the individuals in the kth generation. Did anyone know this recursion in this connection?

Comment: I suppose you could say $u_{k+1}=u_k+\frac{1}{2}u_{k}-\frac{1}{2}u_{k-1}$ where the last two terms represent births and deaths.

Comment: But then sometimes are not full individuals, what should mean a half individual?